# Large Scale IIS with PHP

Tags: linux, windows, apache-2.2, php, iis

Are there any issues about using PHP with IIS on a production environment?
I'm asking this because most of people use Linux + Apache + PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has worked well for me in several production deployments of internal-use apps at Customer sites. [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/web/php/) has shown a fairly reasonable commitment to helping the platform work on Windows. Anything to sell more licenses...

In my experience, stick with the recent versions of PHP and Windows and you'll have no problems. I remember, 4 - 5 years ago, having repeated IIS crashes when the ISAPI-based PHP interpreter would fail on IIS 6 but that's ancient history.

Answer (score 0):

Works Awesome!

http://php.iis.net/

Just go there and you can get the package from MS that installs it and everything